# What should I do if the "Logging Process" failed?

Tags: design-patterns, logging

I log my app errors. but if the logging process failed for some reasons ( database error , no space in the hard disk .. etc ) . how can I know that ? How to log the failed log.

example :

```
try{

    this_will_throw_exception();

}catch(Exception e){

    result = Log.error(e.getMessage());
    if( result == false)
        {
         // what should I do ?
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep your application code simple, i.e. not to worry about logging failure and delegate the logging failure to the logger itself.

Hence your application code should look like:

```
try{
  this_will_throw_exception();
} catch(Exception e){
  Log.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Now we look at how to handle failure in logger.

First, there is a lot of logging framework that provide appender failover. For example there us a FailoverAppender in log4j that log to secondary appender if the primary failed. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

If you choose to build your own logging layer for whatever reason, you may find the decorator pattern useful to build failover logger yourself.

```
public interface Logger {
  boolean error(String message);
}

public DataBaseLogger implements Logger {
  ...
}

public FileLogger implements Logger {
  ...
}

public FailoverLogger implements Logger {
  private Logger primary;
  private Logger secondary;

  public boolean error(String message) {
    boolean succeed = primary.error(message);
    if (! succeed) {
      secondary.error("Primary logger failed");
      secondary.error(message);
      // Try to restart the primary logger, however it might be difficult.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things which come to my mind:

- Recreate the log / change the configuration (file, storage, etc.).
- Send the log to a remote place.
- Show the user a dialog (if applicable) in order to report this error through e-Mail or similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{

    this_will_throw_exception();

}catch(Exception e){

    result = Log.error(e.getMessage());
    if( result == false)
        LoggingFallback.Invoke(e);

    //important, don't hide exceptions
    throw;
}

public class LoggingFallback
{
    public static void Invoke(Exception exception)
    {
       // send an email or whatever

       // if that fails: throw  (include original exception as inner)
       throw new LoggingFailedException("Failed to log exception", exception);
    }
}
```

Motivation:

If logging is important, make sure that it always succeed or make the application fail if it can't. Otherwise you'll eventually end up with an application that have stored no logs.

Also do not catch exceptions without rethrowing if you can't properly handle them: http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/do-not-catch-that-exception/